# Override toString method for a field in Spring 4 + Hibernate + Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I'm a newbie in Spring 4 + Hibernate + Thymeleaf.

I have myEntity.class which implements the model. 
Inside i define all the getter and the setter and i override the
"toString()" method:

```
   /**
     * override toString method
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s(id=%d, title='%s', descripion=%s, enabled=%d)", 
                this.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                this.getId(), this.getTitle(), this.getDescription(), this.getEnabled());
    }
```

Everything until here is ok.

Now i would like to ovveride only the toString() method over the field "Enabled".
So, when i'm in html file template (thymeleaf), i want to print

"Enabled" (when the field is 1)
"Not Enabled" (when 0).

In my project, i will have to do this conversion for every table, so i'm searching 
the best way to do this

I tried something like this before having the idea of using toString method:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${my_entity.enabled== 1}? #{button.label.enabled} : #{button.label.not_enabled}" disabled="disabled"></input>
```

(i know, this doesn't work because of syntax)

Any help or suggestion is welcome.  Thank you

edit:
as i couldn't find a better solution, i do this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <input th:if="${my_entity.enabled == 1}" type="text" class="form-control" th:value="#{button.label.enabled}"  disabled="disabled"></input>
    <input th:if="${my_entity.enabled == 0}" type="text" class="form-control" th:value="#{button.label.not_enabled}"  disabled="disabled"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:value="((${my_entity.enabled} == 1) ? 'Enabled' : 'Not Enabled')" disabled="disabled"></input>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
You can't override the toString() method of a field you have to override the class assuming your enabled field is of String class

```
public class ExtendedString extends String
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
         //override logic here
    }
}
```

Now it looks like enabled is a boolean I would use the `BoolenUtils.toString(boolean, trueString, falseString)` class see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html

Comment: Thank you very much, i tried in so many ways to write that in only one row but i couldn't find the right syntax. This is a good solution, but i'm still curious if someone can answer my main question: if it's possible or no override "toString()" method over one table field

Comment: thank you @ohiocowboy for your good explanation. If i understood well, the "toString override" of your code is the same i wrote in my question. But now, at least, you confirmed me that it's not possible what i want to do.